# Create new column as per value in another column in SQL/powerBI

Tags: sql, powerbi, hana

I have a dataset like:

```
ID    TYPE  POM   POM_new
1234   sys   100   100
1234   pm    101   100
2345   pm    300   302
2345   sys   302   302
```

I want to create new column (POM_new) as mentioned above. The new column should take the "POM" field value based on TYPE field i.e. "sys" .

I want to do it in **SQL(HANA) or Powerbi**. Tried with below code but no success.

```
POM New = CALCULATE(MAX(tablename[POM]),FILTER(LPR,tablename[TYPE]="SYS"),ALLEXCEPT(LPR,tablename[ID]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the standard SQL with analytical function as follows:

```
SELECT ID, TYPE, POM, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'sys' THEN POM END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS POM_NEW
  FROM YOUR_TABLE T;
```

Comment: Great it worked . Thanks for the learning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a **measure**, use this below code-

```
POM_new = 

var current_id = MIN(your_table[ID])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table[POM]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table),
        your_table[ID] = current_id 
        && your_table[TYPE] = "sys"
    )
)
```

In case of **Custom Column**, try this below code-

```
POM_new_column = 

var current_id = your_table[ID]

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table[POM]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table),
        your_table[ID] = current_id 
        && your_table[TYPE] = "sys"
    )
)
```

This below image is just for a cross check. Are you creating the **New Column** from as shown in the below image? If the answer is yes, there is no reason of getting issue for the column code-

[image]

Comment: The custom column  is throwing error like CALCULATE not a function. Could you please check if anything wrong i am doing.

Comment: Hi @kumarb, Where you are trying to create the column. It should be in report part, not in power query editor. I have tested both Measure and Custom column here and working fine for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for response. I am using direct query and I did create a new column just by right click on the table name and then New column on Fields pane

Comment: Try it in report editor >> right click on table >> create new coulumn.

Comment: I did the same . but not of help. The measure one is working good but not the column. I am not sure what is the issue. Calculate is compatible with measure , is that the reason?

Comment: No issue with calculate. Both working here for me. I will check details later.

Comment: @kumarb can you please check my updated answer?

Comment: sorry for delayed response. The error is due to the fact that i am using in Direct query mode ( as per company guidelines). The error msg says - function 'CALCULATE' is not allowed as part of calculated column DAX expressions on DirectQuery models. I suppose you are using in Import mode, hence working

Comment: Yes, that could be the reason.